# Does an angle become twice larger in a right triangle if the correspondence 1:3 becomes 1:1.5? (tangent)

Tags: trigonometry

> Does an angle become twice larger in a right triangle if the (tangent) correspondence $1:3$ becomes $1:1.5$?

I do in fact know that it isn't true.
$$2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right) \neq \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{1.5}\right)$$
But I don't know why and would like to know.

Comment: beacause $\tan x$ is not simply a multiple of $x$ (the graph is not a straight line)

Comment: It's basically the same as asking if $\tan x$ is a linear function. It isn't. For really small values of $x$ you can sometimes approximate $\tan x \approx x$ ($x$ in radians) but in general this isn't true.

Comment: Yeah I know that but how can I explain that tan x isn't a linear function

Comment: Related (duplicate?): ["Why is the tangent of 22.5 degrees not 1/2?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1169871/409) See, in particular, [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1170345/409). ... When you get down to it, the whole reason trigonometry exists as a subject is to bridge the *very* different behaviors between side-lengths and angle-measures in a triangle.

Comment: I read you answer but I am having trouble understanding it.